# Why org.graalvm.polyglot used instead of javax.script package on GraalVM Community Edition?

Tags: java, graalvm

I have a java application working on **java-8-openjdk-amd64** and it evaluates java script. Now I installed GraalVM Community Edition **graalvm-ce-19.2.0** (ubuntu 18.04) and tried evaluate some javascript samples with `org.graalvm.polyglot.Context`
and they are works, but I was surprised when found old java script code crashes and stack trace shows it was evaluated with **org.graalvm** package instead of **javax.script**:

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
            ...
            ScriptEngine engine = 
            scriptFactory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
            engine.put("form", postedAnswer);
            engine.put("question", jsQuestion);
            engine.put("answer", jsAnswer);
            engine.eval(validationJS); //here Exception thrown
```

Here stack trace:

```
javax.script.ScriptException: org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (getData) on JavaObject[com.researchforgood.survey.surveyengine.JSQuestion@504641f2 (com.researchforgood.survey.surveyengine.JSQuestion)] failed due to: Unknown identifier: getData
    at com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine.GraalJSScriptEngine.eval(GraalJSScriptEngine.java:348)
    at com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine.GraalJSScriptEngine.eval(GraalJSScriptEngine.java:323)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at com.researchforgood.survey.surveyengine.service.StepService.validateAnswers(StepService.java:233)
    at com.researchforgood.survey.surveyengine.service.StepService.processAnswers(StepService.java:95)
    at com.researchforgood.survey.surveyengine.HttpSurveyHandler.doPost(HttpSurveyHandler.java:160)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at com.researchforgood.api.apigateway.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (getData) on JavaObject[com.researchforgood.survey.surveyengine.JSQuestion@504641f2 (com.researchforgood.survey.surveyengine.JSQuestion)] failed due to: Unknown identifier: getData
    at <js>.:program(<eval>:6)
    at org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:344)
    at com.oracle.truffle.js.scriptengine.GraalJSScriptEngine.eval(GraalJSScriptEngine.java:346)
    ... 25 more
```

This confuses me a lot. I never saw such behavior with JVM before. Does it mean Graalvm virtual machine does not compatible with Java virtual machines?

I saw polyglot.js.nashorn-compat property mentioned to make polyglot work same way as Nashorn, though this not answers my question because I not use org.graalvm.polyglot in code which crashes.

Answer (score 8):

GraalVM/JavaScript is the JavaScript engine used in GraalVM to execute JavaScript code. It is based on org.graalvm.(polyglot), thus you see that in your stacktrace, nothing to worry about in general. For compatibility reasons, GraalVM/JavaScript provides an implementation of javax.script, but that is only a wrapper around the (preferred) org.graalvm.polyglot.Context to interact with such an engine.

The concrete error you see might be caused by your script trying to access resources that are restricted by GraalVM's sandbox by default. You need to pass additional parameters to allow such access, e.g.:

```
//create engine as in your example, then:
Bindings bindings = engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
bindings.put("polyglot.js.allowAllAccess", true);
engine.eval(validationJS);
```

Again, note that this might increase your security attack surface, only execute trusted code this way (and with ScriptEngine in general)!

For more options and how to interact with GraalVM/JavaScript using a ScriptEngine, see https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/ScriptEngine.md

Hope this helps,
Christian